# Is a phrygian cadence iv6 - V or can it also be VI - V?

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions, cadence

I have always thought that a phrygian cadence was VI - V but I now read that it is actually iv6 - V. Can both be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Phrygian half cadence is exclusively iv<sup>6</sup>–V, not VI–V.

One of the reasons is that the PHC very often has scale-degrees 4 to 5 in the soprano voice. (This isn't a requirement—they can be in an inner voice—but it's very very common.) And since there's no scale-degree 4 in the VI chord, it's not a viable option for this cadence.

By the way, the presence of the 4–5 foreshadows the eventual evolution of augmented-sixth chords: composers and performers alike shaded this 4 up to ♯4, giving that characteristic augmented-sixth interval that would become so popular.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Your replies are very helpful and it seems you know all about the material I am learning. So what kind of cadence is VI - V? this is a very common chord progression.

Comment: @armani Happy to help! If VI moves to V and the phrase ends there, it's just a regular old half cadence; there's no specific name given to it if the V is preceded by VI. But if it's a larger pattern of I–bVII–bVI–V, we do call that the [Andalusian cadence](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/8162/21766).

Comment: aaah ok, I remember that. Actually that is the progression I am most familiar with and I was getting it mixed up with the phrygian cadence. Thanks